# In Rails 3 how should I manage a model column with limited choices

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, drop-down-menu

In my Rails 3 application I have numerous models that have columns that have limited choices (IE a select box). It seems overkill in these cases to create another model and a relationship to the original model just to manage the choices.

One option I can think of is to just create a select box and have the choices in there, but that doesn't seem very DRY. Does anyone have a good suggestion how to handle this situation?

Thanks for looking.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You could create a constant in your model like so

```
# formatted as an array of options, option being an array of key, value
OPTIONS = [['Email', 'email'], ['Text', 'text'], ['Email and Text', 'both']]

validates_inclusion_of :field, :in => OPTIONS
```

Which can then be used to populate a select menu in a view very easily

Example using formtastic

```
<%= f.input :field, :as => :select, :collection => Model::OPTIONS %>
```

Comment: I'm getting a "not in list" error when it tries to validate. Any idea why? I've got `OPTIONS = [['Option 1',1],['Option 2',2]…]` and the form (using @Austin Taylor's view code, `f.select`) is outputting `<option value="1">Option 1</option>` which is what I'd expect. I've checked that it's properly sending it - it is. But it's saying telling me that the value I've sent is not in its list. Any idea why?

Comment: ah you will need to collapse the array into only the values, something like `OPTIONS.collect{|o| o[1] }`

Comment: There it is! I knew there would be a way to do that, but I couldn't find it. I ended up turning it into a hash (`{ 0 => "Option 0", 1 => "Option 1"… }`), which appears to mean I can leave `OPTIONS` alone. Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

I usually do this with a constant list in the model.

```
class Model < ActiveRecord::Base
  PROPERTY_OPTIONS = ['Option One', 'Option Two', ...]
  validates_inclusion_of :property, :in => PROPERTY_OPTIONS
end
```

And in the view:

```
<%= f.select :property, Model::PROPERTY_OPTIONS %>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the enum_column plugin: https://github.com/electronick/enum_column

You can then render your select boxes in your views as follows:

```
<%= f.select :status, Model.columns_hash['status'].limit %>
```

(Where Model is an example model name, such as Book or Product, or whatever it is your application is really about.)

Answer (score 0):

In some cases, I will just create a hash of options and use Class Methods to display and set them.  For example, a Problem model with different statuses could be done like so:

```
def self.statuses
  {:open => 1, :closed => 2}
end
```

Then you just store the integer value in the status_id of the model.  You can configure getters/setters as well.